# glibc version for aarch64

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glibc, libc

I'm cross-compiling an application for `aarch64` on my `x86 Ubuntu Bionic` system, and I have problems with `glibc` version mismatch. My cross-compile toolchain was using v2.27, while the system that is to run the application has v2.24. I thought that it might be due to my toolchain having a too high version, so I decided to downgrade.

After removing all previous cross-compilation installs, I installed `gcc-4.8-aarch64-linux-gnu` (as I had successfully cross-compiled the application with this version on a different host system), thinking that it would install an older `aarch64` version of `glibc` to `/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/`. However, again, v2.27 was installed (I verified that this directory didn't exist before installing the new cross-compilation toolchain).

So my question is twofold:

1. What determines which `aarch64` version of `glibc` is installed on my system when installing `gcc-4.8-aarch64-linux-gnu`? Is it directly tied to my own system's `x86` version of `glibc`?
2. Is there a correct way to install the `aarch64` version of `glibc` v2.24 (or lower) on my system?

Comment: The answers to your questions completely depend on the cross-toolchain you use. There are many of them. It looks like the one you installed has a bug, where system headers leak into the toolchain sysroot. Otherwise, a glibc version mismatch would not be a problem at all.

Comment: The cross-toolchain I tried with, I obtained by ```sudo apt install gcc-aarch64-linux-gcc```. However, when I downloaded this one https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-4/aarch64-linux-gnu/gcc-linaro-4.9.4-2017.01-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz it worked, as it includes ```glibc``` v2.19.

I can't explain why installing via ```sudo apt get``` always installed v2.27...

Comment: So I did some looking around, and came up with a hypothesis: I see that ```gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu``` depends on ```libc6-dev-arm64-cross```. Looking at https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libc6-dev-arm64-cross I see that it defaults to v2.27 for ```Bionic```. So essentially, it's installed as a dependency, and the newest version is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I concur with your hypothesis. After battling similar symptoms for 40 hours straight, I've discovered this confirmation:

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/gcc-10-aarch64-linux-gnu
- https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu

Note that Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish) and Debian 11 (Bullseye) have packages for a gcc 10 cross compiler. Be wary of the very confusing fact the Ubuntu's default package is actually gcc 11, but Debian 11's default is gcc 10. The similar version numbers of Debian and gcc are a coincidence. Also ignore for now the fact that Ubuntu's package is gcc 10.3.0 and Debian's is gcc 10.2.1.

Focus instead on the recommendations and dependencies of each package. Ultimately the Ubuntu package calls up libc >= 2.34, while the Debian package calls up libc >= 2.28.

Sure enough, when I cross-compile from Impish on x86 for Bullseye on aarch64 (despite having a complete SYSROOT for the target), I get this at runtime:

`/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.34' not found`

But your question remains, is there any tie between the host libc and that used by the cross-compiler? The answer is a definite maybe.

See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154015/216323) excellent answer and links for an overview of a cross-compiler. The take-away:

> You don't just cross-compile glibc, you need to cross-compile an entire toolchain. Toolchain components are ALWAYS: ld + gcc + libc + gdb.

So the C library is an integral part of the cross-compiler.

What shenanigans then, are going on when you install `gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu`? It's just a compiler - only one of the four parts of a toolchain.

Well apparently there's some *flexibility*. Technically, a cross-compiler can be *naked*. That's typically only useful when you're compiling an operating system, rather than an executable that runs *on* an operating system. So you can construct special toolchains for special purposes.

But for the standard purpose (cross compiling for Linux on another architecture) you want a typical toolchain. Which is where the package's dependencies and recommendations come in. A `gcc` is always in want of an `ld` which is always in want of a `libc`, and the ménage à trois is intimate. In fact, `gcc` is *built* with `libc` using `ld` in a complex do-si-do. See this example from a [great guide](https://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/) by Preshing on Programming:

[image: cross-gcc-steps]

It's possible to force separation and [link to other libraries](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds?action=recall&rev=21#Compile_against_glibc_in_an_installed_location), but it's not easy.

For example, the linker you use has a set of *default search directories* that are baked in. From the [fine manual](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld.1.en.html):

> The default set of paths searched (without being specified with -L) depends on which emulation mode ld is using, and in some cases also on how it was configured.

And it gets more intwined. By default, `gcc` will call on a *dynamic linker* whose location is hard-coded. For a cross-compiler, it might be something like `/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1`. Not only that, the *executable* may also end up with the hardcoded path, as its [program interpreter](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Tips_and_Tricks/Loader_Tips_and_Tricks).

Again, if you're careful you can tear apart the toolchain and [override things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52454603/3697870). But not only is it tricky to enforce, particularly if you have a complex build, the multitude of combinations of options and paths means there are also often [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356152/3697870). So your host environment can easily leak into your cross-compiling toolchain.

So in summary, cross-compiling requires a *toolchain*. While pulling a cross-compiler from a package manager seems like an easy and legitimate thing to do, it comes with a lot of implicit baggage. You can either carefully follow the package dependencies to check what version you're getting, or use one of the many dedicated toolchain environments, such as `crosstool-NG`.

Comment: Really interesting - thanks for having a sharing!